# Are locknut forks and quick release forks the same and interchangeable?

Tags: wheels, quick-release, dropouts

I have a frame+fork that had old style locknuts on the wheels. I used those wheels for a project. Now I want to put wheels back onto this frame, but I only have quick release wheels in the same size.

My question is can I install the quick release wheels on this bike that previously had locknut on it?

Are the dropouts different widths and are not interchangeable, or can I use these quick release wheels on the same frame?

Thanks!

Comment: Do the dropouts have lawyer lips ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably. If they were bolt on then a quick-release hub will likely fit. Both are 100mm width.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE.  Although you likely have a correct answer here (I have done this interchange myself 30 years ago), your answer is weak in its current form.  Back it up with some examples and more data, including any situations where it would not interchange.  SE sites are NOT like a typical forum: We are looking for defendable answers.  Not my rules, but the rules of the exchange.  If you don't, your answer will likely be downvoted, flagged, and deleted.  Make it more defendable and useful to avoid that.  Look at other highly voted up answers here for good examples.